# Java Android Eclipse R.id

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I would like make a simple application for Android using Bluetooth.
So I looked upon some examples on the web and I've found one.
However I have an error in my `MainActivity.java`.
There is only one error but it is not noticed in the 'console';
It's just underlined in red.
Due to this problem, I can't run the project.

This is my Main :

```
package com.testbluetooth;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.testbluetooth.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import java.util.Set;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    TextView out;

    // Called when the activity is first created. 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

   @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;

    //------here the error underlined by Eclipse: -------
    out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);


    // Getting the Bluetooth adapter
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    out.append("\nAdapter: " + adapter);

    // Check for Bluetooth support in the first place 
    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if(adapter==null) 
    { 
        out.append("\nBluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.");
        //return;
    }

    // Starting the device discovery
    out.append("\nStarting discovery...");
    adapter.startDiscovery();
    out.append("\nDone with discovery...");

    // Listing paired devices
    out.append("\nDevices Pared:");
    Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = adapter.getBondedDevices();
    for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) 
    {
        out.append("\nFound device: " + device);
    }
}
}
```

And this is *activity_main.xml* in the layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/out"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The id class in *R.java* :

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int menu_settings=0x7f070001;
    public static final int out=0x7f070000;
 }
```

So It's with the line *`out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);`* that I've the problem. I've cleaned the project, I tried to create a new xml file in the layout, change out's name, but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `return true;` to the very end of your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method so it is just *before* its closing brace. Eclipse must be complaining about unreachable code.

I'd also recommend **not** doing anything else in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, this should be only for making the options menu, not modifying a UI element part of the Activity's layout (in this case, your `out` TextView).